# How to set degrees to a maximum of 360?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a program and I want to let my snake go in the same direction it is heading, but when I try this code:

```
def move(self):
    if pressed_keys[self.ctrls[0]]and self.dire == 0:
        self.y -= 10
    if pressed_keys[self.ctrls[0]]and self.dire == 90:
        self.x -= 10
    if pressed_keys[self.ctrls[0]]and self.dire == 180:
        self.y += 10
    if pressed_keys[self.ctrls[0]]and self.dire == -90:
        self.x += 10

def turn_left(self):
    self.dire += 90

def turn_right(self):
    self.dire -= 90
.
.
.
while 1:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_LEFT:
            snake.turn_left()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_RIGHT:
            snake.turn_right()
    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
```

there is a problem:
I can turn twice with the right arrow-key but I can't go in that direction anymore. That is because what I did was: I pressed the arrow twice -> self.dire - 90 - 90. So self.dire is now -180. I could change the values: I could change

```
if pressed_keys[self.ctrls[0]]and self.dire == 180:
    self.y += 10
```

to

```
if pressed_keys[self.ctrls[0]]and self.dire == 180 or -180:
    self.y += 10
```

but if I press the right arrow another four times, I must then add the value -540 and so on. Does anyone know a better solution? Or can you say that self.dire must be between -360 and 360 degrees?

Comment: Have you tried division by modulo (`%` operator)?

Comment: No, how should I use it?

Comment: It returns the rest of the division operation, so `450 % 360` returns `90`, for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based off @Pavlus suggestion to use the modulo `%` operator, along with a few formatting fixes to make viewing easier.

```
def move(self):
    self.dire = self.dire % 360

    if pressed_keys[self.ctrls[0]]:
        if self.dire == 0: self.y -= 10
        if self.dire == 90: self.x -= 10
        if self.dire == 180: self.y += 10
        if self.dire == 270: self.x += 10

def turn_left(self):
    self.dire = (self.dire + 90) % 360

def turn_right(self):
    self.dire = (self.dire - 90) % 360
.
.
.
while 1:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_LEFT:
            snake.turn_left()
        if event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_RIGHT:
            snake.turn_right()
    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
```

Answer (score 2):

Change `turn_left` and `turn_right` to use the modulo operator.

```
def turn_left(self):
    self.dire = (self.dire + 90) % 360

def turn_right(self):
    self.dire = (self.dire - 90) % 360
```

`a % b` operator returns the remainder when `a` is divided by `b`, so `self.dire` will stay within the range [0, 360).

You will also have to change

```
if pressed_keys[self.ctrls[0]]and self.dire == -90:
```

to

```
if pressed_keys[self.ctrls[0]]and self.dire == 270:
```

Or, even better, use trigonometric functions.

```
import math

def move(self):
    if pressed_keys[self.ctrls[0]]:
        self.x += 10 * int(math.cos(math.radians(self.dire)))
        self.y += 10 * int(math.sin(math.radians(self.dire)))
```

In that case, you wouldn't even need the modulo operator, but it might be nice to keep it around.